# How to set default values for each selectlist value....in a repeat tag

Tags: visualforce, picklist, selectlist, repeat

```
<apex:page controller="Questions_Controller">
<apex:form >
    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <apex:repeat value="{!ques}" var="singleQuestion">
            <tr>
                <td>{!singleQuestion}</td>

                <td>
                    <apex:actionRegion >
                        <apex:selectList value="{!Selectedvalues}" size="1">
                            <apex:selectoptions value="{!objectivetype}" />
                                <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!populateAnswers}" reRender="dummy">
                                    <apex:param assignTo="{!answeredQuestion}" value="{!singleQuestion}" name="answeredQuestion"/>
                                </apex:actionSupport>
                        </apex:selectList>
                    </apex:actionRegion>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>
    <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!submitAnswers}" rerender="dummy"/>
</apex:form>
```

Please find below the controller:

```
 public class Questions_Controller
{
    public List<SelectOption> objectivetype{get; set;}

    public String Selectedvalues{get; set;}

    public List<String> ques{get; set;}

    private Map<String, String> questionAnswerMap;

    public String answeredQuestion{get; set;}

    public Questions_Controller()
    {
        ques=new List<String>();
        ques.add('Question 1');
        ques.add('Question 2');

        objectivetype=new List<SelectOption>();
        objectivetype.add(new SelectOption('yes', 'yes'));
        objectivetype.add(new SelectOption('no', 'no'));
        objectivetype.add(new SelectOption('Maybe', 'Maybe'));
        objectivetype.add(new SelectOption('dontknow', 'dontknow'));

        questionAnswerMap=new Map<String, String>();
    }

    public void populateAnswers()
    {
        questionAnswerMap.put(answeredQuestion, Selectedvalues);
        Selectedvalues=Null;
    }

    public void submitAnswers()
    {
        system.debug('questionAnswerMap---->'+questionAnswerMap);
        Selectedvalues=Null;
    }
}
```

This is working fine.

### Now I want implement or extend the logic like this down below....

Can I set the default values for each selectlist value....in a repeat tag.

I mean, in detail..,

can I set 'YES' fro some fields and 'NO' for some fields and 'May be' for some fields and remaining 'DonKnow'
based on some conditon ....for example

if  'singleQuesthion' ==' do_u_like_this_event '.....then for that 
  should be'YES' "default values should be this.(in apex repeat tag)

if 'singleQuesthion' ==' do_u_like_to_appy_now '.....then fro that 
 SELECTEDVALUES should be 'NO'

if 'singleQuesthion' ==' r_u_intrested_in_doing_business '.....then fro that 
 SELECTEDVALUES should be 'May be'

.
.
.

Like this...based on some condition of 'Single Question' automatically 
corresponding default values must appear in

apex:selectlist value.....which is in apex:repeat tag.

**Please help me out solving this issue.**

Answer (score 1):

I still think a simple nested class is the right way to go. It also allows a default answer to be set in the controller for each question.

Visualforce:

```
<apex:page controller="Questions_Controller">
<apex:form >
    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <apex:repeat value="{!questions}" var="q">
            <tr>
                <td>{!q.label}</td>
                <td>
                    <apex:selectList value="{!q.answer}" size="1">
                        <apex:selectoptions value="{!selectOptions}"/>
                    </apex:selectList>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </apex:repeat>
    </table>
    <apex:commandButton value="Submit" action="{!submitAnswers}"/>
</apex:form>
```

Controller:

```
public class Questions_Controller {
    public class Question {
        public String label {get; set;}
        public String answer {get; set;}
        Question(String label, String answer) {
            this.label = label;
            this.answer = answer;
        }
    }
    public List<SelectOption> selectOptions {get; set;}
    public List<Question> questions {get; set;}
    public Questions_Controller() {
        // You can have a label that is different from the value
        selectOptions = new List<SelectOption>{
                new SelectOption('yes', 'Yes'),
                new SelectOption('no', 'No'),
                new SelectOption('maybe', 'Maybe')',
                new SelectOption('dontknow', 'Don't Know')
                };
        // All the questions and their default answers
        questions = new List<Question>{
                new Question('Question 1', 'maybe'),
                new Question('Question 2', 'no')
                );
    }
    public PageReference submitAnswers() {
        // If you really want the map as the result you can built it here
        Map<String, String> questionAnswerMap = new Map<String, String>(); 
        for (Question q : questions) {
            questionAnswerMap.put(q.label, q.answer);
        }
        // Do something with the map
        return null;
    }
}
```